# How to add specific Play Services APIs in Command-Line Android projects? (Such as LocationServices)

Tags: android, command-line, out-of-memory, google-play-services, location-services

At the moment, I'm building a Scala + Android app with SBT. I'd rather not use Gradle.

I'd like to use the Google Play Services Location-Services API to grant me GPS coordinates. I don't need any of the other Play Services. When I include the whole library, though, it times out with an [OutOfMemory error like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded), and sources online suggest Multidexing as a solution to the problem. I don't want to do that at all. There's no need.

So, I'm interested in [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) here. In the 'Android Studio' section, it gives the option to select only certain APIs in the library for your app (e.g. Wearables = compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0', Fitness = compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.8.0', etc). In the 'Other' and 'Eclipse' sections, though, this is absent.

How do you choose to compile only certain APIs of the Play Services library? Is it possible, without using Gradle + Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.android.gms"  % "play-services-wearable" % "7.8.0"
```

Etc

If you run out of memory while dexing, increase

```
dexMaxHeap in Android
```